# C# HttpClient Missing Cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, httpclient

A correct session (shown via fiddler), shows that the following cookies need to be sent (_atuvc, _utma, utmz, and JSESSIONID).

Via my C# HttpClient, I do have one cookie being sent, but I don't know why only one (JESESSIONID) is being sent.  The relevant code follows.

```
// Create Handler
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

// Cookies
var cc = new CookieContainer();
handler.CookieContainer = cc;

// Create the client
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

// headers, form data, etc

var request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri1);
...
var response1 = await client.SendAsync(request1);
....
var request3 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri3);
....
var response3 = await client.SendAsync(request3);
```

No login is required to observe the web application problems (with cookies).  You can surf to https://www.ltu.se/ideal

Then click on "Antagen till kurs".

The in the "Ange kurskod" box type "a0004n".

Then click on "Lista anm"...

Then select 17113 and click at the bottom "Sök".

Thanks!!!

Comment: These cookies (_utma is used by Google Analytics, _atuvc is by a service called "AddThis") are not automatically set by your C# client.  Did you set these cookies somewhere else and not include that code here?

Comment: I did it through Chrome using the Developer Tools. I only see 1 cookie being sent (JSESSIONID)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe the analytics cookies are a result of the browser parsing the page and executing javascript.  Since you C# client isn't doing that, you don't get those cookies.  But I doubt they are relevant; look at something more like the UserAgent string.